# mysql dynamic row_number generation issue

Tags: mysql, row-number

I tried creating a row number for the MySQL based on the references from web.

The query is as below.

There is a condition when the audit id is NOT same the `row_number` variable needs to be incremented by 1. Otherwise the `row_number` is same[incremented per row].
However, since there is a reference in `having; condition{[row_number>3]}`, the `row_number` gets incremented once again.

So, I am getting odd numbers as `row_number` in the result. Please help. 
That means the result of the below query has `5,7,9,`etc., as `row_number` rather than `4,5,6,`etc.,

Note: Here the `AUDIT_ID` column is big integer.

```
SELECT  
 @row_number:=CASE WHEN @audit_id = AUDIT_ID then @row_number
    else
@row_number+1 
end AS row_number,
@audit_id:=AUDIT_ID as AUDIT_ID from 
(
SELECT AUDIT_ID from AUDIT where <somecondition>
UNION ALL
SELECT AUDIT_ID from AUDIT where <somecondition>
)
TABLE ,(SELECT @row_number:=0, @audit_id:=0) AS temp 
   having row_number >3
```

Comment: its better if you include some sample data and table definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fix order of `AUDIT_ID` column they must be ordered in order to have correct `row_number` for this i have added `ORDER BY AUDIT_ID` in union part then you are using `having` clause for alias `row_number` it will re run/evaluate the expression defined against your `row_number`(i.e case when ...) alias therefore your `row_number` is not same as you expect for filter out the results that are less than 3 you need to wrap you whole query in another sub select like `select * from (your query) t1 where some conditon`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  
        @row_number:=CASE WHEN @audit_id = AUDIT_ID
        THEN @row_number
        ELSE @row_number+1 
        END AS row_number,
        @audit_id:=AUDIT_ID AS AUDIT_ID
     FROM (
        SELECT AUDIT_ID FROM AUDIT WHERE <somecondition>
        UNION ALL
        SELECT AUDIT_ID FROM AUDIT WHERE <somecondition>
        ORDER BY AUDIT_ID
        ) t,
       (SELECT @row_number:=0, @audit_id:=0) AS temp 
) t1
WHERE row_number >3
```